# Retrieve image path from assets folder

Tags: android, path, assets

I have issue to retrieve image path from assets folder.

I have an image folder in assets folder. Within the folder i have three different folders.

Here is the code that i used:

```
String IntroImage1= "" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;


try{
    AssetManager mngr =getAssets();
    InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open(IntroImage1);
    //InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("image/Malay/bullet.png");

    Bitmap bitmapBullet = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BulletImgInput);
    BulletImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapBullet);
    }catch(final IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am wondering why can't i display the image? Because I have try to retrieve it through this code:

```
InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("image/Malay/bullet.png");
```

It did retrieve the file, but with the string that i replaced in **mngr.open** it doesn't show up.

Really need you guys to help up.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the AssetManager. You can do

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/image/Malay/bullet.jpg")`

Though storing Images in the Assets is not the best way to go. You will not be able to take advantage of the Android resource management system. So unless you have a compelling reason to do this, I'd suggest that you take a look at using the `res` folder and the resources system.

Update: Explanation
The `BitmapFactory` has a method to decode a file via the `decodeFile` method. That's point one. Android lets you access a file in the `assets` folder via the `file:///android_asset/{path}` path. In your case, the Image at /image/Malay/bullet.jpg is the `assets` folder can be accessed via the the `file:///android_asset/image/Malay/bullet.jpg`.

Comment: Ya i have certain reason to use assets file. Can you briefly tell me how the code you provide works? Sorry i m super new to android. THanks

Comment: This does not work for me. I get a file not found exception. Even though i use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/anims/x.gif", options);` the logcat error shows it as `FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/anims/x.gif`. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
try {

    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");

    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {

      Log.e("I/O ERROR","Failed when ..."
}
```

your BulletImage

Answer (score 3):

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/NewFile.txt";

String url = "file:///android_asset/logo.png";
```

you can access any file....

Comment: but it is not a txt file. It is a .png file. So any other suggestion?

Comment: @YuenTong you can also access png files dear

Comment: It doesnt work for me. TT When i use this code: **InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("image/Malay/bullet.png");** , It works. but not to replace the url by the string assign by different variable. I already try to debug it by displaying the **String IntroImage1= "" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;** and i got the same path as this **"image/Malay/bullet.png"**

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("file:///android_asset/image/Malay/bullet.png");
```

Maybe this could work for u.

Comment: It doesnt work for me. TT When i use this code: **InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("image/Malay/bullet.png");** , It works. but not to replace the url by the string assign by different variable. I already try to debug it by displaying the **String IntroImage1= "" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;** and i got the same path as this **"image/Malay/bullet.png"**

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is in missed `image` part of path?

```
String IntroImage1= "image/" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;
```

instead of

```
String IntroImage1= "" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;
```

Upd: Check values of `languageSelected` and `Intro1ImagePath` also.

Comment: this is my directory: assets --> image ---> (3 different folder with the image inside). So i think including the ""image/" is needed right?

Comment: @YuenTong Yes, including of "image/" is needed.

Comment: It doesnt work for me. TT When i use this code: **InputStream BulletImgInput = mngr.open("image/Malay/bullet.png");** , It works. but not to replace the url by the string assign by different variable. I already try to debug it by displaying the **String IntroImage1= "" + languageSelected + "/" + Intro1ImagePath + ".png" ;** and i got the same path as this **"image/Malay/bullet.png"**

Comment: @YuenTong I see in your code that you use `ImagePath` variable instead of `IntroImage1`. What is value of `ImagePath`?